# Azure VM cannot 'see/access' another Azure VM

Tags: networking, azure

We have 2 Azure VM's, each on different VNET's. They both run Sql Server.

I can connect to to both VM's from my home office/IP using Azure Data Studio.
My home office has a static IP. I've made sure those VM firewalls are allowed to accept my connection.

Now, VM_A cannot connect to VM_B using Sql Server Management Studio (because that's provided by default when Sql Server is installed). VM_A *can* connect to other sql server instances, like Azure Sql.

I'm really not sure how to debug this.

First of all, the dns name I'm using to connect is a FQDN and it resolves to `52.x.y.z` (so it's not a CLASS A|B|C ip range).

I'm not sure if this is a NIC issue on the VM? So here's some info about the NIC's..

`VM_A`

[image]

`VM_B`
[image]

What I don't get is that I can totally connect to VM_B Sql Server (port 1433) from my home/office, but the image above says there no NIC Public IP?

I thought of VNET peering the 2x VNET's but when I try that, there's an IP Overlapping occurring, so that prevents the peering from working.

Anyone have any suggestions? If there's specific data needed to help solve this, I can add more pics upon request. I'm just not sure what to add, right now.

Answer (score 0):

vNets are a boundry in Azure, so by default a VM in one vNet will not be able to communicate with one in another. To resolve this you can either peer the networks (the most secure option) or add a rule in the VM's NSG to allow traffic  from the public IP of the other VM. This should resolve the connectivity issue.

On the lack of public IP on VM B, if you can connect from the outside world then it must be getting an IP from somewhere. If one is not assigned to the VM directly, then is there are load balancer in front of the VM or similar? Can you see an IP object in Azure?